# How to invert if condition in applescript with multiple expression

Tags: applescript

I have the following script working fine:

```
if {title is equal to "missing value" or title starts with "Your stream on"} then
  return ""
else
  try
    return "♫  " & title
  on error err
  end try
end if
```

I want to invert this if condition into something like this:

```
if {title is not equal to "missing value" or not title starts with "Your stream on"} then
  try
    return "♫  " & title
  on error err
  end try
end if
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the correct logical inversion of

```
a OR b
```

is

```
not a AND not b
```

And no braces and AppleScript speaks real English

```
if title is not missing value and title does not start with "Your stream on" then
```

Answer (score 0):

Stupid mistake. My syntax was incorrect. The following works:

```
if {title is missing value or not title starts with "Your stream on"} then
  try
    return "♫  " & title
  on error err
  end try
end if
```